# Can you disable the wifi on the BT Voyager 2000 wireless modem?

Tags: wireless-networking

I use an Aiport Extreme for my wifi (on 802.11n), so I’d rather have the modem’s wifi switched off. (I’m also starting to think it might be interfering with my Aiport’s wifi signal.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think we’ll call this a “no”.

Answer (score 0):

Paul, most BT Voyager modems are accessed through a webpage, default address is 192.168.1.1, (enter in web browser address bar)

Next you will most likely need a username and password, default is usually admin & admin.. you should have access to most functions from here.

Comment: Yup, got all that going on. There doesn’t seem to be an option in the admin screens to turn the wifi off though.